# How to start WildFly server without joining a cluster

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing, wildfly, wildfly-8

We have five Wildfly (8.2.0-Final) servers running in different machines on the same network. When I start them, by default they come under a single cluster.

But I don't want this to happen. I want each of them act as a standalone server. I believe in JBoss-5 we can achieve this by passing `-g` option which would create a separate partition and thus a separate cluster.

Is there any similar option for WildFly? Please suggest. I don't want to run them in a cluster.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you starting your 5 wildfly instances? you can disable clustering by not using a HA profile to start your jboss instance or you can define a unique multicast address for each instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am starting using HA profile itself. I tried starting with unique multicast address for each of them, but still they look in the cluster. Also I found HornetQ are coming together in cluster. One way to avoid this by not setting cluster password. But is there a common way to achieve this. I don;t want HornetQ to be in cluster. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the HA profile if you are not wanting the instances to cluster. That should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. Started JBoss with standalone-full configuration file, which eventually started standalone.

Comment: You don't need standalone-full unless you are planning to use the hornetq subsystem (ie. your application is using JMS). Otherwise just standalone.xml should be fine for you and you will use up less memory footprint and get faster startup.

Comment: My application uses JMS and hence need hornetq. Consequently I have to choose standalone-full.xml configuration. Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want JBoss Wildfly to start in a cluster, use the non-HA standalone profiles such as `standalone.xml` or `standalone-full.xml` if you require messaging/JMS.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are particular to start with clustering mode and exclude clustering of two instance, change the jgroups address (udp/tcp) while starting